# JSON Schema nested dependencies

Tags: jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I want to conditionally render an input field depending on a checkbox checked.

This checkbox is nested and I dont know how to access it.

I got this to work:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firstName": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "firstName": {
              "enum": [true]
            },
            "lastName": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[example here](https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/#eyJmb3JtRGF0YSI6eyJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOmZhbHNlfSwic2NoZW1hIjp7InR5cGUiOiJvYmplY3QiLCJwcm9wZXJ0aWVzIjp7ImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiYm9vbGVhbiJ9fSwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzIjp7ImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6eyJvbmVPZiI6W3sicHJvcGVydGllcyI6eyJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOnsiZW51bSI6W3RydWVdfSwibGFzdE5hbWUiOnsidHlwZSI6InN0cmluZyJ9fX1dfX19LCJ1aVNjaGVtYSI6e30sInRoZW1lIjoiYm9vdHN0cmFwLTQiLCJsaXZlU2V0dGluZ3MiOnsidmFsaWRhdGUiOmZhbHNlLCJkaXNhYmxlIjpmYWxzZSwib21pdEV4dHJhRGF0YSI6ZmFsc2UsImxpdmVPbWl0IjpmYWxzZX19)

Now what if the dependency is nested like so?:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "enabled": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "test": {
      "enabled": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "enabled": {
                "enum": [true]
              },
              "lastName": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see: I have tried to access it but it is not recognized correctly.
How would I approach this problem? Is this even possible?

[JSON Scheme Validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) says its valid

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "properties" under "dependencies" -> "test". Everything under that point is not recognized as a schema.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "enabled": {
          ...
```

"dependencies" is documented here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#id5.

Comment: thank you I got a rendering. But sadly it does not behave as expected. it should render the text-input if the checkbox is checked. would you say that this is ensured by the given schema? (because if yes, then the react library would be to blame) is there a method to achieve this goal?

Comment: In terms of schema correctness, yes, but that won't do what's expected in the form, I think. I'm not sure exactly what they want, and what I've cooked up looks odd data wise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to have the `dependencies` in the same schema object as the property... like this

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "enabled": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "enabled": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "properties": {
                "enabled": {
                  "const": true
                },
                "lastName": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but I don't know if the resulting data is what you would expect.

I'm an expert with JSON Schema, but I've never used the form generation tooling.